# Plotting sorted values in a faceted ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble plotting sorted values inside each facet using ggplot2.

Here is the sample plot[image]

```
ggplot(data=df) + 
    geom_point(aes(y=log(count_neg,10), x= ref_name, colour=replicate)) +             
    facet_grid(condition ~ sub_groups)
```

What I would like to do is sort the points in each facet by Y values. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
ggplot(data=df) + 
    geom_point(aes(sort(y=log(count_neg,10),decreading=TRUE), 
                   x= ref_name, colour=replicate)) + 
    facet_grid(condition ~ sub_groups)
```

Raw data here:

```
df<-structure(list(condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("N_0m", "N_10m", "N_1h", "N_24h", "N_2h", 
"N_30m", "N_48h", "N_6h", "N_8h"), class = "factor"), replicate = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    ref_name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
    22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
    34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
    46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
    58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
    70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 
    82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
    39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
    51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
    63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
    75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 
    87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L), .Label = c("ERCC-00002", "ERCC-00003", 
    "ERCC-00004", "ERCC-00009", "ERCC-00012", "ERCC-00013", "ERCC-00014", 
    "ERCC-00016", "ERCC-00017", "ERCC-00019", "ERCC-00022", "ERCC-00024", 
    "ERCC-00025", "ERCC-00028", "ERCC-00031", "ERCC-00033", "ERCC-00034", 
    "ERCC-00035", "ERCC-00039", "ERCC-00040", "ERCC-00041", "ERCC-00042", 
    "ERCC-00043", "ERCC-00044", "ERCC-00046", "ERCC-00048", "ERCC-00051", 
    "ERCC-00053", "ERCC-00054", "ERCC-00057", "ERCC-00058", "ERCC-00059", 
    "ERCC-00060", "ERCC-00061", "ERCC-00062", "ERCC-00067", "ERCC-00069", 
    "ERCC-00071", "ERCC-00073", "ERCC-00074", "ERCC-00075", "ERCC-00076", 
    "ERCC-00077", "ERCC-00078", "ERCC-00079", "ERCC-00081", "ERCC-00083", 
    "ERCC-00084", "ERCC-00085", "ERCC-00086", "ERCC-00092", "ERCC-00095", 
    "ERCC-00096", "ERCC-00097", "ERCC-00098", "ERCC-00099", "ERCC-00104", 
    "ERCC-00108", "ERCC-00109", "ERCC-00111", "ERCC-00112", "ERCC-00113", 
    "ERCC-00116", "ERCC-00117", "ERCC-00120", "ERCC-00123", "ERCC-00126", 
    "ERCC-00130", "ERCC-00131", "ERCC-00134", "ERCC-00136", "ERCC-00137", 
    "ERCC-00138", "ERCC-00142", "ERCC-00143", "ERCC-00144", "ERCC-00145", 
    "ERCC-00147", "ERCC-00148", "ERCC-00150", "ERCC-00154", "ERCC-00156", 
    "ERCC-00157", "ERCC-00158", "ERCC-00160", "ERCC-00162", "ERCC-00163", 
    "ERCC-00164", "ERCC-00165", "ERCC-00168", "ERCC-00170", "ERCC-00171"
    ), class = "factor"), count_neg = c(468869L, 34677L, 113226L, 
    23508L, 8655L, 9319L, 210L, 25675L, 928L, 53981L, 8878L, 
    22507L, 5880L, 11756L, 21688L, 95L, 2397L, 6553L, 2533L, 
    12714L, 110L, 13520L, 71598L, 3177L, 55453L, 4157L, 3391L, 
    2740L, 144203L, 52L, 10710L, 15576L, 22028L, 5328L, 42474L, 
    1906L, 2829L, 12753L, 1207L, 351477L, 28401L, 5523L, 1166L, 
    7515L, 2773L, 17744L, 757L, 16316L, 16855L, 1236L, 16087L, 
    5447L, 358290L, 29127L, 34571L, 159457L, 630L, 46067L, 5977L, 
    22835L, 4014L, 111972L, 12372L, 5396L, 8183L, 1293L, 210L, 
    734814L, 10174L, 12838L, 39742L, 4259L, 35927L, 801L, 16309L, 
    16153L, 133685L, 8209L, 4331L, 5319L, 6029L, 3074L, 4768L, 
    2274L, 4958L, 9128L, 7243L, 2946L, 14718L, 20577L, 11257L, 
    78889L, 2407687L, 116262L, 52712L, 47998L, 10892L, 10124L, 
    479L, 19437L, 1257L, 61059L, 31119L, 25751L, 10645L, 14689L, 
    20248L, 92L, 3168L, 11003L, 3396L, 16732L, 176L, 29809L, 
    77936L, 12340L, 155159L, 5336L, 3818L, 3127L, 163497L, 66L, 
    14612L, 12687L, 25586L, 6996L, 25554L, 2284L, 3667L, 15745L, 
    1444L, 1033128L, 20087L, 17619L, 1412L, 11946L, 8014L, 19551L, 
    978L, 24182L, 22125L, 1717L, 14514L, 4564L, 903132L, 33653L, 
    39776L, 173518L, 796L, 35684L, 6524L, 62638L, 14418L, 398893L, 
    7938L, 6422L, 10595L, 1563L, 572L, 370134L, 10825L, 13837L, 
    17794L, 5164L, 43831L, 1114L, 17244L, 18924L, 171171L, 10228L, 
    5789L, 6847L, 6467L, 3582L, 6834L, 3084L, 7450L, 12474L, 
    6399L, 2390L, 22084L, 20090L, 7961L, 192521L), sub_groups = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("condition", 
"replicate", "ref_name", "count_neg", "sub_groups"), row.names = c(NA, 
184L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your raw data code doesn't work.

Comment: @panda : try it now .. I have removed other columns and made it more compact. Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Also I am just copy pasting dput(df)..may be formatting is getting messed up.

Comment: guys try the copying the raw data now. should work..thanks for the patience

Comment: There is no `ref_name` in your example data.

Comment: @BrianDiggs : Sorry man ..I am having real trouble pasting dput output here. Any tips on how should I paste the dput string ..I have tried it once more but doest seem to work

Comment: If you mean how to format the `dput` output like a code block, just highlight all of it and press the `{}` button above the editing area. That will indent the entire selection by 4 spaces which will give you formatting as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df$ref_name <- reorder(df$ref_name,-log(df$count_neg,10))    

ggplot(data=df) + 
    geom_point(aes(y=log(count_neg,10), x= ref_name, colour=replicate)) +             
    facet_grid(condition ~ sub_groups)
```

or omit the minus sign if you want the opposite ordering. This orders the x axis by the (global) y value. If you intended to order each facet separately, that is somewhat more complicated, in part because it makes the graph considerably more confusing.

Comment: thank for editing my question and fixing the df : 1) Could you please help me understand how you were able to fix the dput output. It will be helpful in future. 2) after reordering I think the plot looks nicer but I have a question. How did the global reorder of ref_name based on log(count_neg) got the order corrected in a facet level. Also what if I sort the values inside ggplot, aes section. It doesnt work the same way. I think I have some confusion about mapping of values to aesthetic by ggplot. Thanks a lot

Comment: (1) All I did was format it by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button, (2) Probably because the ordering is fairly consistent from panel to panel, but if you look closely, you'll see that some aren't quite in decreasing order, I think, (3) simple arithmetic transformations are pretty safe inside `aes`, but in general you should make changes in the data frame.

Comment: thanks ..for 2) any way we can sort at facet level then. I want to make sure that each facet has strictly decreasing order. I tried using plyr but dint work out. Basically I want to arrange the data frame by (conditions,replicate,sub_groups, count_neg) with count_neg in the decreasing order for condition,replicate,sub_groups ... makes sense ?

Comment: @Abhi The whole point of faceting is that the panels _share a scale_. If the x axis values are sorted in different orders for each panel, that is by definition no longer a common scale. Hence faceting is sort of non-sensical. Perhaps you want to plot each panel separately and then arrange them using `grid.arrange` from **gridExtra**.